# Android set on drag listener is showing error

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing an android app using drag and drop. And also I am using an a broadcast receiver for screen on. When I am using `setOnDragListener` It shows an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=init view flg=0x10 } in com.app.lockscreenlibrary.LockBroadcastReceiver@f22ed7d
```

Can anybody please help me solve the issue? Here is my code:

**ActivityView.java**

```
public class ActivityView extends FrameLayout {

public LinearLayout drop;
TextView text,sucess;
int total , failure = 0;
ImageView viewDrop;

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

private Context mContext;

Button btnUnlock;


Button btn1;

private int CLICK_ACTION_THRESHHOLD = 200;
private float startX;
private float startY;


public ActivityView(Context context) {
this(context, null);
}

public ActivityView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ActivityView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

init(context);

}

private void init(final Context context) {
mContext = context;
View view = inflate(context,R.layout.activity_view,null);

gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new SingleTapConfirm());

drop = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear);
sucess = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Sucess);

drop.setOnDragListener();

drop.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    //return false;

    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action) {

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        break;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        break;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        break;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:{
        failure = failure+1;
        return(true);
      }

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:{
        total = total +1;
        int suc = total - failure;
        sucess.setText("Sucessful Drops :"+suc);
        text.setText("Total Drops: "+total);
        return(true);

      }

      default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
  }
});


btnUnlock = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.unlock);

btnUnlock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    LockHelper.getLockLayer().unlock();
  }
});

btn01 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn0);

btn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                          @Override
                          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                            Log.d("LockView", "onTouch");

                            switch (event.getAction()) {

                              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                startX = event.getX();
                                startY = event.getY();
                                break;
                              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                float endX = event.getX();
                                float endY = event.getY();
                                if (isAClick(startX, endX, startY, endY)) {
                                  Log.d("LockView", "clicked");
                                } else {

                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); //specific to my project
                            return false;



                          }
                        });




        addView(view);
}

}
}

private class SingleTapConfirm extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
  Log.d("LockView", "clicked1");
  return true;
}

}

private boolean isAClick(float startX, float endX, float startY, float endY) {
float differenceX = Math.abs(startX - endX);
float differenceY = Math.abs(startY - endY);
if (differenceX > CLICK_ACTION_THRESHHOLD/* =5 */ || differenceY > CLICK_ACTION_THRESHHOLD) {
  return false;
}
return true;
}
}
```

**LockBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
final public class LockBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = LockBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

private volatile boolean bInterruptSupervisor = false;

private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mExecutor;
private FutureRunnable mSupervisorRunnable;

private static final int SCHEDULE_TASK_NUMBER = 3;

private PhoneStateChange mPhoneStateChangeCallback;

public void assignPhoneStateChangeCallback(PhoneStateChange phoneStateChangeCallback) {
mPhoneStateChangeCallback = phoneStateChangeCallback;
}

@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String mAction = intent.getAction();

//DU.sd("broadcast -----The Intent Action is: ", "" + mAction);

switch (mAction) {
  case LockHelper.INIT_VIEW_FILTER:
    LockHelper.INSTANCE.initLockViewInBackground(context);
    break;
  case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON:
    refreshBatteryInfo();
    bringLockViewBackTopIfNot();
    break;
  case CoreIntent.ACTION_SCREEN_LOCKER_UNLOCK:
    shutdownScheduleExecutor();
    break;
  case LockHelper.START_SUPERVISE:
    bInterruptSupervisor = false;
    supervise(context.getApplicationContext());
    break;
  case LockHelper.STOP_SUPERVISE:
    bInterruptSupervisor = true;
    break;
  case LockHelper.SHOW_SCREEN_LOCKER:
    //DU.sd("broadcast", "locker received");
  case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
    LockHelper.INSTANCE.initialize(context);
    LockHelper.INSTANCE.getLockLayer().lock();
    bInterruptSupervisor = true;
    break;
  case Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED:
    //LockHelper.INSTANCE.getLockView().batteryChargingAnim();
    break;
  case Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED:
    //LockHelper.INSTANCE.getLockView().batteryChargingAnim();
    break;
  case Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN:
    break;
  case "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE":
    TelephonyManager tm =
        (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    switch (tm.getCallState()) {
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        mPhoneStateChangeCallback.ringing();
        Log.i(TAG, "RINGING :" + intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number"));
        break;
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        mPhoneStateChangeCallback.offHook();
        //DU.sd(TAG, "off hook");
        break;
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        mPhoneStateChangeCallback.idle();
        Log.i(TAG, "incoming IDLE");
        break;
    }
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
}

abstract class FutureRunnable implements Runnable {

private Future<?> future;

public Future<?> getFuture() {
  return future;
}

public void setFuture(Future<?> future) {
  this.future = future;
}
}

public void supervise(final Context context) {
//DU.sd("service", "supervise");

initScheduleExecutor();

if (mSupervisorRunnable == null) {
  mSupervisorRunnable = new FutureRunnable() {
    public void run() {
      if (bInterruptSupervisor) getFuture().cancel(true);

      boolean cameraRunning = false;
      Camera _camera = null;
      try {
        _camera = Camera.open();
        cameraRunning = _camera == null;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // fail to open camera, secure to ignore exception
        //DU.sd("camera exception on supervise");
        cameraRunning = true;
      } finally {
        if (_camera != null) {
          _camera.release();
          getFuture().cancel(true);
          context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(LockHelper.SHOW_SCREEN_LOCKER));
        }
      }

      if (!cameraRunning) context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(LockHelper.SHOW_SCREEN_LOCKER));
    }
  };
}
Future<?> future =
    mExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(mSupervisorRunnable, 2000, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
mSupervisorRunnable.setFuture(future);
}

private void bringLockViewBackTopIfNot() {
initScheduleExecutor();
mExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    LockHelper.INSTANCE.getLockLayer().requestFullScreen();
  }
}, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private void refreshBatteryInfo() {
initScheduleExecutor();
mExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    //LockHelper.INSTANCE.getLockView().refreshBattery();
  }
}, 2, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

private void initScheduleExecutor() {
if (mExecutor == null) {
  synchronized (this) {
    if (mExecutor == null) mExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(SCHEDULE_TASK_NUMBER);
  }
}
}

public synchronized void shutdownScheduleExecutor() {
if (mExecutor == null) return;

mExecutor.shutdown();
mExecutor = null;
}
}
```

**LockHelper.java**

```
public enum LockHelper implements SwipeEvent {
INSTANCE;
private static Context mContext;

private final int UNLOCK = 830;
private final int UNLOCK_WITH_PASSWORD = 831;
private final int SWITCH_TO_GUEST = 345;

public static final String INIT_VIEW_FILTER = "init view";
public static final String START_SUPERVISE = "start supervise";
public static final String STOP_SUPERVISE = "stop supervise";
public static final String SHOW_SCREEN_LOCKER = "show screen locker";

private static LockView mLockView;
private static LockLayer mLockLayer;

public void initialize(Context context) {
    initContextViewAndLayer(context);

    loadLockView(context);
}
/**
 * @throws NullPointerException if not init
 */
public static LockView getLockView() {
    if (mLockView == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("init first");
    return mLockView;
}

/**
 * @throws NullPointerException if not init
 */
public static LockLayer getLockLayer() {
    if (mLockLayer == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("init first");

    return mLockLayer;
}

/**
 * @throws NullPointerException if context == null
 */
public void initLockViewInBackground(final Context context) {
    if (context == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("context == null, assign first");

    if (mLockView == null || mLockLayer == null)
        initContextViewAndLayer(context);
}

public void initContextViewAndLayer(Context context) {
    if (mContext == null)
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mContext == null)
                mContext = context;


        }

    //init layout view
    if (mLockView == null)
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mLockView == null)
                mLockView = new LockView(context);
        }

    //init lock layer
    if (mLockLayer == null)
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mLockLayer == null)
                mLockLayer = LockLayer.getInstance(context, mLockView);
        }
}

private volatile boolean mIsInitialized = false;

public void loadLockView(Context context) {
    mLockView.showLockHome();

    if( !mIsInitialized){
        //mLockView.assignSwipeEvent(this);
        //
        //mLockView.assignDirectionOperator(new SwipeWithAnimListener.DirectionOperator() {
        //    @Override
        //    public void up() {
        //    }
        //
        //    @Override
        //    public void down() {
        //
        //    }
        //
        //    @Override
        //    public void left() {
        //        if(!mLockView.leftSlidable()) return;
        //
        //        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(UNLOCK);
        //    }
        //
        //    @Override
        //    public void right() {
        //        if(!mLockView.rightSlidable()) return;
        //
        //        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(UNLOCK);
        //    }
        //});

//            mLockView.assignPinCodeRuler(new PinCodeView.UnlockInterface() {
//                @Override
//                public void onUnlock(String password) {
//
//                    Message msg = new Message();
//                    msg.what = UNLOCK_WITH_PASSWORD;
//                    msg.obj = password;
//                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
//                }
//
//                @Override
//                public void onBack() {
//                    mLockView.switchBackToCenterFromBottom();
//                }
//            });

        mIsInitialized = true;
    }

    mLockLayer.lock();
    showLockLayer();
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case UNLOCK:
                //DU.sd("handler", "unlock");

                unlock();
                break;

            case UNLOCK_WITH_PASSWORD:

                if (!(msg.obj instanceof String)) break;
                String password = (String) msg.obj;
                switchUserIfExistOrAlertUser(password);

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void unlock() {
    mLockLayer.unlock();
    //mLockView.stopShimmer();

    mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(LockHelper.STOP_SUPERVISE));


    mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(CoreIntent.ACTION_SCREEN_LOCKER_UNLOCK));
}

private void switchUserIfExistOrAlertUser(String password) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        wrong();
        return;
    }

    if (!password.equals("1234")) {
        wrong();
        return;
    }

    unlockScreenAndResetPinCode();
}
private void unlockScreenAndResetPinCode() {
    unlock();
//        mLockView.resetPinCodeView();
}

private void wrong() {

}


public static final String INTENT_KEY_WITH_SECURE = "with_secure";

@Override
public <S, T> void onSwipe(S s, T t) {


    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LockHelper.INSTANCE.getLockLayer().removeLockView();
        }
    }, 1000);

    //triggerCameraWithSecure(mContext, !(t instanceof Boolean) || (Boolean) t);
}

private void triggerCameraWithSecure(Context context, boolean withSecure) {
    //if (!CameraHelper.hasCameraHardware(context)) return;
    //
    //try {
    //    CameraHelper.cameraStrategy(context, withSecure);
    //} catch (Exception e) {
    //    // may cannot open
    //    e.printStackTrace();
    //    showLockLayer();
    //}
    //
    //context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(LockHelper.START_SUPERVISE));
}


private void showLockLayer() {

    mLockView.showLockHome();
    mLockLayer.bringBackLockView();
}

public void vibrate(long milliseconds) {
    if (mContext == null) return;
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
    v.vibrate(milliseconds == 0 ? 500 : milliseconds);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete exception stack instead of just one line

Comment: I have added complete error in my question.

Comment: I modified question and i added LockHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the boradcast receiver per se. You have a clear exception in your code

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.happiness.lockscreenlibrary.LockScreenService cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnDragListener at
```

You are trying to cast an incompatible class type to another. I could not see that part of code in what you pasted here. So, please try to figure that out. Basically the code you are executing on receiving the broadcast has a bug, nothing with the receiver as such

Comment: Where are your LockHelper and LockView classes ?

Comment: LockView is ActivityView.java.

Comment: I am sorry for file name changing

Comment: I modified question and i added LockHelper.java .